# Multiplayers online game (MMO) | Architecture | Learning Path

Tags: unity-game-engine, architecture

I want to learn game development.

I'm coming from Web, Desktop and Mobile Applications.
where is no really REAL-TIME programming.

And all architecture templates and life cycles is very different.
Now I have 1 idea for game. I don't know if this will very good game, but for first game my main goal is - Get experience

My game is online game with 2 players.
The players has cards (like in Clash Royal)  and will player release the card - game need to do something.

Now question is in Architecture....
In applications that I made - all business logic was on SERVER SIDE..........
But If i understand right - here is Game on Players phone do all business logic..and server is just "message provider" ??

The second question is - If I have to use online service (like Photon) or build my TCP/UDP server.. (Its not so hard and for first game I think I can do it by myself)

UPDATED:

The main question what is resources I need to read for get more information about type of Architectures in Game Dev?

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no RIGHT ANSWER for your question, as there are many ways to do an on-line game, and everyone have their pros and cons, like:

Host & Clients, where one of the players is acting like a server.
Authoritary Server, where all the logic is calculated on one side, and then update the others.

If you are working on Unity I recommend you to look the different network api's over there: Photon, Unet...

You can use the server services that Unet provides, or build your own system.

But one advise: don't mess with physics on on-line games, will be punishing.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - In "my server" I mean only message provider - like user press A, or user put Card XUZ to desc etc... no more